# App shows the log as Received memory warning and crashes while scrolling images faster in uiscrollview?

Tags: memory-leaks, crash

In my application,i need to load 'n' number of images in uiscrollview for scrolling horizontally(forward and backward). There is two way to scroll images. First one is, get all the images from data base and added into uiscrollview. another one is, get each images from data base for each scrolling with respect to forward and backward actions. I followed by second way. my problem is that,the app crashes only in ipad while scrolling images forward and backward faster, it shows the log as 'Received memory warning'. i released every allocated objects properly. And even i checked the leak itself,there is no leak on that.. what is the problem? why it happens only in ipad? thanks in advance.

Thanks,
wesley

Answer (score 0):

When the app receives memory warning iOS automatically deletes some of the loaded resources like images, views etc. It can cause the crash in some way. You should not load all the images at once in the scrollView. You should load images dynamically according to the index of the image on the scrollView. And release the image when the index changes. Or you can load only 3/4 images at a time in the memory so that the user doesn't experience any loading time while scrolling. Load/release the images in the background as the user scrolls.

Comment: @ Saleh,i did not load all the images at once. i loaded the images dynamically only.. even it happens

Comment: Then they must not be releasing correctly. Also we should not store the images in the database, it becomes too heavy. Images should be store in the physical memory(documents dic etc) or on some sever.